# Internal error: Huge input lookup on safari when parse xml to json

Tags: javascript, json, xml

I got an issue when I try to parse a XML file with about 600000 lines 
When I run my web on chrome it work with little bit slow
But when I run it on Safari I got error parser "Internal error: Huge input lookup"
I use library https://github.com/abdmob/x2js

The error message I got.

```
<parsererror xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black">
<h3>This page contains the following errors:</h3>
<div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">error on line 523674 at column 25: internal error: Huge input lookup</div>
<h3>Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.</h3>
```

Thanks for read my question.

Comment: Based on some searching it appears there is a size limit on the input to the underlying XML parser. Confirm this by testing with smaller input. And then if this is the case you're going to to have to accept doing processing in parts.

Comment: Hi Richard,
So do you know why it worked normally on chrome but got error on safari?
Thanks!

Comment: Different browsers use different XML parsers with different limitations (and bugs).

Comment: @Chung Le: Because Safari uses a different JavaScript engine...